# Update destination directory with new files (if modified) using ant

Tags: ant

I'm facing a problem with ant "copy". Here is my requirement:
I want to sync 2 dirs(dir1 and dir2) but i want to keep the extra files/dirs present in dir2. My aim is i want to copy dir1 contents(if modified ) to dir2 but want to keep any additional files/dirs present in dir2.

I tried ant's sync task, but it is trying to keep both dirs in sync ie., it is deleting extra contents present in dir2. I don't find any flag to disable this feature:

```
<sync todir="dir2" failonerror="true" verbose="true">                             
<fileset dir="dir1" excludes="*.svn" />
 </sync>
```

I tried ant's copy with "modified" selector, but its also doing the same: :(

```
<copy todir="dir2" failonerror="true">
  <fileset dir="dir1" excludes="*.svn" >                           
     <modified/> <!-- Copies only modified files -->
  </fileset>
```

Can any one suggest, how can i achieve my requirement with ant?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ANT copy task does not overwrite files:

```
<copy todir="target/dir2" verbose="true" overwrite="false">
  <fileset dir="src/dir1"/>
</copy>
```

The copy task will also detect if the file has changed.

The copy task will not delete files, so I don't understand why your second example (using a modified selector) did not work.

Comment: Sorry for the spam. My second solution is working as expected. I didnt check it properly :(